# I'm getting an error when I try to send embeds

Tags: javascript, discord.js

With this code:

```
if (message.content === `${settings.prefix}commands`) {
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('commands test')

        message.channel.send(embed)
    }
```

I am getting this error:

> Object.defineProperty(this, 'client', { value:message.client});
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'client' of undefined

and i don't know where that is or how to fix it.
i have tried redoing my code in different ways and nothing has worked, so if someone could help me that would be great! :)

Comment: Can you provide me with your full code? It would be helpful as I don't know how you're making the bot. And what is `Object.defineProperty(this, 'client', { value:message.client });` for?

Comment: The whole code, including where it uses `Object.defineProperty(this, 'client', { value:message.client });` If possible, and the whole error debug as well.

Comment: i dont know what  `Object.defineProperty(this, 'client', { value:message.client });` is or does but it says the directory is "C:\Users\joe momma\Desktop\coding\projects\1stbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\ " and wdym full code? like the whole bot source?

Comment: Okay, so that's the discord.js module's source, thanks for the info. I'll look into it, sorry for the late reply, I'm at school. Are you using discord.js v11.x or v12.x? I think that's the issue, but can you be more specific? @oxidize

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is because you're using `discord.js^11.x` which uses `Discord.RichEmbed()` instead of `Discord.MessageEmbed()` used by v12.x. Try checking these official discord.js pages for info on the update:
[Docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/updating) || [GitHub](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/releases/tag/12.0.0) || [Guide](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html)
Try changing your code to:

```js
if (message.content === `${settings.prefix}commands`) {
  const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setTitle('commands test')
  message.channel.send(embed);
}
```

And I suggest using `message.content.startsWith()` instead of `message.content ===` like such:

```js
if (message.content.startsWith(`${settings.prefix}commands`)) {
  const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setTitle('commands test')
  message.channel.send(embed);
}
```

And if you would, it's better to update discord.js to v.12 since it has more features. After updating, change your code to:

```js
if (message.content.startsWith(`${settings.prefix}commands`)) {
  const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle('commands test')
  message.channel.send(embed);
}
```

And don't forget to revise everything else shown in the links above from your code, otherwise more errors would be thrown.